# Plotting a stacked bar graph from a dataframe where all bars are of same color

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am struggling to plot a simple stacked bar-graphs. Currently I have a dataframe with same unique values for two columns, like:

```
df
    col1 col2
  0  1    2  
  1  1    2  
  2  2    1  
  3  3    3 
  4  5    5 ...
```

I want to plot a stacked bar-graph for these two colunns, using unique values present as a single bar.

I have tried to create two different arrays to plot using seaborn as below:

```
df1=  df.col1.value_counts()
df2=  df.col2.value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(18, 12))
sns.barplot(df1.index, df1.values, alpha = 0.8, color=p[0], label = 'event')
sns.barplot(df2.index, df2.values, alpha = 0.4,color=p[1], label = 'hour')
```

But I get

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: what is your `p` ?

Comment: Thanks... forgot about that.. was code from something else... solved now :)